# How to get desired result set using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is my table structure:-

```
Table01
ID  Name    FkID  dateTime
1   John    1     2012-06-01
2   Peter   2     2012-06-02
3   Penny   2     2012-06-03
4   Patty   3     2012-06-01
```

I tried this query but :(

```
select * 
from Table01 
where FkID in 
(SELECT FkID FROM Table01 GROUP BY FkID HAVING ( COUNT(PkID) < 2 ))
order by dateTime desc
```

Desired Results:-

```
1   John    1     2012-06-01
3   Penny   2     2012-06-03
4   Patty   3     2012-06-01
```

I need unique results by FkID but from duplicate FkID I need to pick row up by latest datetime. Any guide line please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to achieve that.

```
WITH A AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FkID ORDER BY dateTime DESC) AS rn
  FROM Table01 
)
SELECT ID, Name, FkID, dateTime
FROM A
WHERE rn = 1;
```

I used a Common Table Expression (the `WITH` statement), but you can do it just as well with a normal subquery. But really, `ROW_NUMBER()` is a blessing when you are want to work with grouped data (or PARTITION'ed, so to say).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by joining on the your table twice.

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.dt
from t t1
inner join
(
    select fkid, max(dt) as dt
    from t
    group by fkid
) t2
    on t1.fkid = t2.fkid
    and t1.dt = t2.dt
order by t1.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2321b/2)